# My very basic python program will not work and I don't know why maybe I am blind and tired but I can't tell

Tags: python

why do i get this error for this:

```
prisoners = input('How many player(s): ')
print = ('Welcome to Prison break!')
if int(prisoners) == 1:
    print('Welcome solo player, bravest of the brave')
elif 2 <= int(prisoners) <5 :
    print('Welcome prisoners, hold on to each other tight')
elif 1 > int(prisoners):
    print('Whoops, this game is 1-4 players. ')
elif 4 < int(prisoners):
    print('Whoops, this game is 1-4 players. ')



err:raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aiyoobaman/Documents/vscode/stuff.py", line 7, in <module>
    print('Welcome solo player, bravest of the brave')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Please help.

Comment: You overwrote `print` in the second line.

Comment: print ('Welcome to Prison break!') remove the equal

Comment: @KlausD. thanks so much I guess I really am tired

Comment: I guess you should catch some sleep ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the second line

```
prisoners = input('How many player(s): ')
print('Welcome to Prison break!')
if int(prisoners) == 1:
    print('Welcome solo player, bravest of the brave')
elif 2 <= int(prisoners) <5 :
    print('Welcome prisoners, hold on to each other tight')
elif 1 > int(prisoners):
    print('Whoops, this game is 1-4 players. ')
elif 4 < int(prisoners):
    print('Whoops, this game is 1-4 players. ')
```